# In spring based application database is incrementing id by 50 not by 1 in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa, sequence

I wrote simple CRUD application using Spring MVC + JPA + Postgresql. When I add data to database manually(using sql query in pgAdmin) the Id sequence increments by 1. But when I add data to my database using my application, the Id sequence increments by 50. Why? How can I configure this sequence to increment by 1 when adding data using application?

Comment: Because that's how the sequence generator works by default. Instead of executing a query at each insert to get the next value, it executes one every 50 inserts and thus keeps a buffer of 50 available IDs in memory, making inserts more efficient. You can set allocationSize = 1 on your sequence generator if you really want to.

Comment: this might help you https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql/